# How to configure a loader for a specific path in webpack

Tags: webpack

In webpack the [`Rule.test` option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruletest) only checks a file's name, not its full path. I have files of the same type in multiple directories and want to apply different loaders based on a file's path, e.g.

```js
{
    test: /aaa\/.*.html/,
    loader: 'loaderA'
},
{
    test: /bbb\/.*.html/,
    loader: 'loaderB'
}
```

Is there any way to make that work?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can use `include` and `exclude` properties ([docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#condition)):

```
{
    test:/\.html$/,
    include: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, "app/pathA")
    ],
    loader: 'loaderA'
},
{
    test:/\.html$/,
    include: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, "app/pathB")
    ],
    loader: 'loaderB'
}
```

For files in folder `pathA` will applied loader `loaderA`, and for `pathB` - loader `loaderB`.

Comment: It is working for me. Link to the new docs: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#condition

Comment: @DouglasGaskell webpack 3 policy is avoiding any breaking changes so such things shouldn't happen. For me it's still working.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use those regexes in the `include` / `exclude` field.

```
{
    test: /\.html$/,
    include: /aaa\/.*.html/,
    loader: 'loaderA'
},
{
    test: /\.html$/,
    include: /bbb\/.*.html/,
    loader: 'loaderB'
}
```

Or using this pattern (useful for combining tailwind with other css processors)

```
{
  test: /src\\index.css$/,  // <- note: windows
  // ...
},
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  exclude: /src\\index.css$/,
  // ...
}
```